# Neuronal Net accuracy is too low

Tags: r, neural-network

I just wrote my first attempt of providing a neuronal network for household classification by using energy consumption features. So far I could make it run but the output seems to be questionable. 
So like you can see I'm using 18 features (maybe to much?) to predict if it's a single or non-single household.

I got 3488 rows like this:

```
c_day     c_weekend c_evening c_morning c_night c_noon c_max c_min r_mean_max r_min_mean r_night_day r_morning_noon
 12        14      1826         9     765      3   447     2        878          0        7338              4
r_evening_noon t_above_1kw t_above_2kw t_above_mean t_daily_max single
 3424           1           695         0       174319075712881     1
```

My neuronal network using these parameters:

```
net.nn <- neuralnet(single
            ~ c_day
            + c_weekend
            + c_weekday 
            + c_evening
            + c_morning
            + c_night
            + c_noon
            + c_max
            + c_min
            + r_mean_max
            + r_min_mean
            + r_night_day
            + r_morning_noon
            + r_evening_noon
            + t_above_1kw
            + t_above_2kw
            + t_above_mean
            + t_daily_max
            ,train, hidden=15, threshold=0.01,linear.output=F)

1 repetition was calculated.

        Error Reached Threshold Steps
1 126.3425379    0.009899229932  4091
```

I normalized the data before by using the min-max normalization formula:

```
for(i in names(full_data)){
  x <- as.numeric(full_data[,i])
  full_data[,i] <- (x-min(x)/max(x)-min(x))
}
```

I got 3488 rows of data and splitted them into a training and a test set.

```
half <- nrow(full_data)/2 
train <- full_data[1:half,]
test <- full_data[half:3488,]

net.results <- compute(net.nn,test)
nn$net.result
```

I used the prediction method and bound it to the actual "single[y/no]"-column to compare the result:

```
predict <- nn$net.result
cleanoutput <- cbind(predict,full_data$single[half:3488])
colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("predicted","actual")
```

So when I print it, this is my classification result for the first 10 rows:

```
            predicted actual
1701 0.1661093405      0
1702 0.1317067578      0
1703 0.1677147708      1
1704 0.2051188618      1
1705 0.2013035634      0
1706 0.2088726723      0
1707 0.2683753128      1
1708 0.1661093405      0
1709 0.2385537285      1
1710 0.1257108821      0
```

So if I understand it right, when I round the predicted output it should be either a 0 or 1 but it always ends up being a 0!

Am I using the wrong parameters? Is my data simply not suitable for nn prediction? Is the normalization wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just tried the mean-standard deviation normalization as you said and it lowered the error down to ~25.

Comment: Good that your error is low now. Now you may want to compare error in between training and test datasets to see if you are overfitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your model performance is still not good. Once you have reached good model performance after tuning you should get correct expected behavior. Neural net techniques are very susceptible of scale difference between different columns so standardization of data [mean =0 std =1] is a good practice. As pointed by OP `scale()` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Using `scale(full_data)` for the entire data did the trick. Now the data is normalized through standard-mean deviation and the output seems much more reliable.